# Scala Play 2.5.X - Dependency Injection with a trait

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, playframework-2.5

I'm using Dependency Injection in Scala Play 2.5

I read the guide for DI and set up my controllers to have injection of the cache:

```
class EventController @Inject()(db: Database, cache: CacheApi) 
  extends Controller with Authentication {

...
}
```

Authentication is a trait that I made in order to specify which endpoints absolutely need a user. This is the definition:

```
class UserRequest[A](
  val uid: Option[Long], request: Request[A]
) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

trait Authentication { self: Controller =>
  var cache: CacheApi = null

  ...

  def translateToken(token: String): Option[Long] = {
    val uidstr = cache.get[Long](token)
    if( uidstr.isDefined ){
      return Some(uidstr.get)
    } else {
      return None
    }
  }

  object AuthenticatedAction extends ActionBuilder[UserRequest] {
    def invokeBlock[A]( request: Request[A], block: (UserRequest[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
      var uid: Option[Long] = None;
      val token = request.session.get("token");
      if( token.isDefined ){
        // verify session is genuine
        uid = translateToken(token.get)
        if( !uid.isDefined ){
          // token is invalid or outdated. reset the session
          request.session - "token"
        }
      }
      block( new UserRequest[A](uid, request)  )
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

I have the cache lib in my build.sbt.

Whenever I try to invoke an action on this controller, I get a null pointer at cache.get. How do I get the injection to not be null, and how do I ensure that the injected value will never be null?

Comment: Make the cache in the trait a `def` and then the cache in the controller a `val` (as josephpconley pointed out).

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered that when using traits with Dependency Injection, the signature of the injected parameter must match that of the trait.

For instance, in `EventController`, I should have used `var cache: CacheAPI` instead of simply `cache: CacheAPI`

Comment: You should really use the immutable `val` instead of the mutable `var` when creating that parameter.  I don't think you'd want that instance of cache to mutate.